# How can I render 3d objects over uGUI?

Tags: unity, gui

I have a scene with 3d objects but need uGUI as background.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: It's a bit old but maybe it'll help you: https://forum.unity.com/threads/draw-3d-object-over-the-ui.289737/

And look at this reddit post too: https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/2sv19r/new_gui_anyway_to_render_3d_objects_above_the_new/